# Unable to open 'Agda': AbstractContextKeyService has been disposed

Tags: visual-studio, agda, agda-mode

I'm trying to use agda-mode on visual studio code on windows 10. I'm getting this error on VSC when pressing `ctrl-c ctrl-l` (or any other) keybinding associated with agda-mode. I had this issue a couple of days ago, but restarting my computer solved it. Now that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks like a regression introduced recently.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue on an M1 mac.  Things like `ctrl-c ctrl-l` just stop working.  Deleting `.vscode`, reinstalling the app, and reinstalling the agda-mode extension eventually worked, but it happened again.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, in the end, was closing the window at the bottom [image] then closing the file and reopening it (in the same VSC instance). Another time setting this [image] to false fixed the issue.